# r-value references and normal variables

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

I am reading the following tutorial: [Learn Cpp](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/15-2-rvalue-references/) and there they put an example of use of a r-value reference.

```
#include <iostream>

class Fraction
{
private:
    int m_numerator;
    int m_denominator;

public:
    Fraction(int numerator = 0, int denominator = 1) :
        m_numerator{ numerator }, m_denominator{ denominator }
    {
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Fraction &f1)
    {
        out << f1.m_numerator << '/' << f1.m_denominator;
        return out;
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto &&rref{ Fraction{ 3, 5 } }; // r-value reference to temporary Fraction

//    auto notref=Fraction(4,8);
    auto notref{Fraction(4,8)};  //<---MY adding 
    // f1 of operator<< binds to the temporary, no copies are created.
    std::cout << rref << '\n';
    std::cout<< notref<<"\n";  //<-- MY adding

    return 0;
} // rref (and the temporary Fraction) goes out of scope here
```

The parts mark "MY adding" are parts added by me for this question.

and they write

> As an anonymous object, Fraction(3, 5) would normally go out of scope
>   at the end of the expression in which it is defined. However, since
>   we’re initializing an r-value reference with it, its duration is
>   extended until the end of the block. We can then use that r-value
>   reference to print the Fraction’s value.

However as you can see I have added a normal variable for comparison and it does *exactly the same*. The Fraction does not go out of scope and it can be normally used in the printing part.

What is the difference and why would someone use the r-value reference?

Comment: `rref` and `notref` are exactly identical other than the behaviour of `decltype(id)`  . The reference part refers to how it was initialized, not how it goes on to behave once created. This use of `rref` would be uncommon; it's most usual to use rvalue or forwarding references as function parameters

Answer (score 2):

In this example, rref only goes out of scope after return 0. It has the same lifetime as notref. So there is no difference.